# Rails 2.3.5 -> Rails3 problem: observe_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 2.3.5 app, I have:

observe_field :searchtype, :url => {:action=>'set_search_type'}, :with => "'search_type=' + value"

This no longer works in Rails3. What's the new way to implement this?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3):

JQuery analogue solutions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchtype").bind("blur", function() {
    var url = '/set_search_type'; //your real url "??/set_search_type"
    var data = {search_type: $(this).val()}; // hash of input names and values for sending to server
    $.get(url, data, // make ajax request
     function(html) { // function to handle the response
    });
  });
});
```

[How to convert this observe_field to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447722/how-to-convert-this-observe-field-to-jquery)

[Rails observe_field using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127529/rails-observe-field-using-jquery)

Comment: please explain this line:  $("#searchtype").bind("blur", function() {

Comment: This string assign event handler for `OnBlur` (focus lost) event to element with `ID=searchtype`